# Determining if a target string is found in an array of strings

Tags: strings, search, coffeescript

I wrote this simple function in CoffeeScript to see if elements are found in an array:

```
isFoundIn = (searchTerm, arrayToSearch) ->
  returnVal = false
  for a in arrayToSearch
    returnVal = true if searchTerm is a
  returnVal
```

Usage:

```
isFoundIn('james', ['robert', 'michael', 'james'])`
```

would return true.

I know in Ruby it is very concise and readable to do this:

```
myArr = ['robert', 'michael', 'james']
myArr.include? 'james'
```

Are there some strategies to refactor this to make it more readable or more like CoffeeScript?

Comment: It seems you've replicated the native JS array `indexOf` function. While there's no exact match for Ruby's `include?` in JavaScript, a simple `array.indexOf(term) isnt -1` will give you the same result.

Comment: Heh, just posted an answer with much the same stuff seconds after your update :)

Comment: That's a reasonable question, but can infer from it that you're not using underscore.js? (or any other functional library for JS/CS). http://underscorejs.org/#contains. `_(myArr).contains("james") #=> true`. I imagine having to write JS without all those extensions and I get the chills...

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on my comment above:

Your `isFoundIn` function can be rewritten as simply

```
isFoundIn = (term, array) -> array.indexOf(term) isnt -1
```

`indexOf` uses the strict `===` comparison, which is what CoffeeScript also uses for `is` - i.e. it's equivalent to your code.

One could extend the native JS Array prototype with a `include` function to more closely mimic Ruby. In CoffeeScript, it'd be written as

```
Array::include = (term) -> @indexOf(term) isnt -1
```

Then you can do `[1, 2, 3].include(3)` and such. But extending native prototypes is generally frowned upon, and I can't recommend it. Tempting though.

As for your original function, you could just do an explicit return right away if the `searchTerm` is found - no need to loop through the rest of the array

```
    isFoundIn = (searchTerm, arrayToSearch) ->
      for a in arrayToSearch
        return true if searchTerm is a
      false
```

The point is moot, though, as `indexOf` does it all for you

---

Addendum: I do like the `?` hack you used to fully match Ruby's method name, but it is still just that: A hack. You're effectively adding `undefined` as a possible return value for what should be a straight boolean. It'll also absorb errors (as that's its purpose) where e.g. the object responds to `indexOf` just fine, but - for whatever reason - hasn't been extended with the `include` function. So it's easy to get false negatives (unless you explicitly start checking for `undefined` and branch if that's the case and... well, the code fogs up quick)

So again, definite points for creativity - wish I'd thought of it - but I personally wouldn't go near it in production code

Comment: Why is extending prototypes generally frowned upon in JavaScript? Is it because you can create compatibility issues hypothetically with future releases of ECMASript and or other libraries?

Comment: @JamesJamesJames: Check SO, there are lots and lots of questions regarding this known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype/8859941#8859941. More orthodox is the "objects-wrapper" that many libraries take (jQuery being the most known example).

Answer (score 4):

Any reason to not use `item in ary` syntax? it compiles down to a slightly convoluted usage of `.indexOf >=0` but it is the coffeescript way.

Answer (score 3):

The `in` in CoffeScript is essentially the same as Ruby's `include?`. You may write following Ruby version

```
['robert', 'michael', 'james'].include? 'james'
```

in CoffeeScript as

```
'james' in ['robert', 'michael', 'james']
```

You can use following if you want to add `include` to Array prototype:

```
Array::include = (o) -> o in @

myArr = ['robert', 'michael', 'james']
console.log 'present' if myArr.include? 'james'
```

Note: `?` in include has different meaning in Ruby and CoffeeScript. In Ruby its the part of function name (although we can use `?` for boolean attributes in Rails). While in CoffeeScript `?` is an operator to check if the operand value is not null.

Comment: Nice answer! But, this is not written very well. Please explain your code, and what improvements you are making from the OP's code.

Comment: @SirPython, does it look any better now?

Comment: Much better! Good job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it "more like CoffeeScript", use array comprehensions:

```
isFoundIn = (searchTerm, arrayToSearch) ->
  return true for item in arrayToSearch when item is searchTerm
  false
```